# What is the efficient way to target and replace or espace quotes within a quoted string?

Tags: javascript

my string is 
{"message":"My name is "Joe"!"}

I need to escape the double quotes in --> "Joe" so that it becomes:
{"message":"My name is \"Joe\"!"}

I can easily do an str_replace routine on the double quotes, but that will also mess with the legit quotes in the string.

I could do some splitting and parsing and all that jazz but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this? Perhaps regex?

Comment: How did your string end up that way?

Comment: Can you give us some code? I'm confused on exactly what's really happening. `str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');` should work?

Comment: @vihan1086 `str.replace('"', '\\"');` will not do global search.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Oh yeah, whoops

Comment: `JSON.stringify( theStringWithMixedQuotes)` will do you right with ease since it always output a valid string.

Comment: I'm also confused. Your string is the whole thing that looks like a litteral object with a syntax error? Most likely you need to do your escaping at an earlier stage. Escaping at this point would require not just parsing (which can usually be done as fast as regex), but smart parsing looking at different outcomes and picking the one without syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

`{"message":"My name is "Joe"!"}` should throw error because of double quotes inside double quotes. Use, single quotes inside double quotes or vice versa.

```js
var string = {"message":'My name is "Joe"!'}

alert(string.message.replace(/(")/g, "\\$1"));
```

Rather using regex, you can construct your message object like,

`{'message': 'My name is "Joe"!'}`

This will reduce the regex overhead

Comment: Once you have an object, there would be no need to escape the double quotes because stringifying the object will do that.